# Shopping Cart ordering tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am developing online Shopping Cart system. Now I need to work on adding the items/basket into order tables.  I wanted to make sure if I'm going on the right path?

These are the main products tables:

**items table**

- item_id (p)
- item_name
- item_description

Note: item prices are in the item_options tables

**item_options table**

- option_id (p)
- item_id (f)
- option_name
- option_price

**item_extras table**

- extras_id (p)
- option_id (f)
- extras_name
- extras_price

Below are the orders tables.  As you can see the item name, option name and extras name, prices are copied into orders tables.  If any of item name or prices changed - it will not affect the order tables. For example the invoices will not be affected.

**orders table**

- orders_id (p)
- customer_id (f)
- address_book_id (f) (for delivery adddress)
- date_purchased
- orders_status
- orders_date_finished

**order_items table**

- orders_items_id (p)
- orders_id (f)
- item_id (f)
- item_name (copied from items table)
- item_description (copied from items table)
- option_id (f)
- option_name  (copied from item_options table)
- option_price (copied from item_options table)

**order_extras table**

- order_extras_id (p)
- orders_id (f)
- orders_items_id (f)
- extras_id (f)
- extra_name
- extra_price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to raise two potential optimisations to this database schema.

Firstly, are there any extras which could apply to two different options e.g. options and extras has a many-to-many relationship? If so you need to add a link table with the following structure:

```
 optionExtras
 optionId, pk
 extraId, pk
```

you then alter the extras table by removing the optionId field. This could remove potential redundancy.

Secondly, instead of duplicating item names, option names and extra names why not add a boolean(0-1) row into each table titled active which signifies which entries in each table are currently possible to be selected at the time of ordering. This way the extra redundancy is avoided and products can be re-instated, without any effect on information on old invoices. When you want to change the price or name of a product you just turn the  current active record to off and then insert a new record with the new information. The old orders obviously still point the correct id of the entry that is not active.

You could also take this one step further and use the active column to signify products which are available to people that type in special codes e.g. label these products active = 2.

Anyway, those are my thoughts, hope they are helpful!

Comment: Thanks for detailed reponse Gordon, I wanted to make sure I understood you correctly. Did you mean to add a new table called "optionExtras" ? I dont understand how would this potential remove redundancy? The way product work: An Item can have many Options. An Option can have many extras.  Secondly in regarding to boolean, did you mean like items.active, item_options.active 1 or 0  ? That is really good idea , thank you :)

Comment: If I change the price or name of a product I would set the active record to off and then insert a new record with the new but that mean I have to update the new item_id in item_options.item_id (FK) table?

Comment: Yes a new table called optionExtras. As you say, an item can have many options and an option can have many extras. But can option 1 have the same extras as option 2, or option 3? Or some of the same options? In which case you a link table to simplify this many-to-many relationship is the best way to solve the possibility of duplicating the same information twice.

Comment: The downside is that you would have to add all the options for the new item very time you want to change something. You could easily write a function that updates this for you though based on your updating of the items table.